Struct vs. arrays performance in Julia
I implemented a simple AVL tree in Julia in two ways.  One is using a node struct:
mutable struct AVLNode{T}
    data::T
    height::Int
    left::Union{Nothing, AVLNode{T}}
    right::Union{Nothing, AVLNode{T}}
end

The other way does not use a node struct, but arrays to hold all the data:
mutable struct AVLTree{T}
    data::Vector{T}
    height::Vector{Int}
    left::Vector{Int}
    right::Vector{Int}
end

Here, instead of pointers I use integers (giving the index of the node in the arrays; so left[i] is the left child of node i, etc.); a zero corresponds to a null pointer (or nothing as in the previous example).
The algorithms I used for both implementations are exactly the same (copies of each other).
I was surprised to find out that the AVLNode implementation is a good 10-20% faster than the implementation with arrays.  It also uses 10-15% more memory (which I can understand).  Any guess for why this is the case?  Perhaps cache locality plays a role (since with nodes all information for a node is nearby)?
Any clues about the best way of going about such an implementation?  In particular, does it make sense to go for a nonrecursive implementation?
Here is the main function for recursively finding/inserting a new node in the tree, for the array implementation.  The implementation with AVLNode is the same, but uses the struct's fields instead:
# This function returns (r, s), where r is the new root, and s is the node 
# containing data, which could be newly inserted.
function find_insert_rec!(tree::AVLTree{T}, r::Int, data::T) where {T}
    if r == 0
        s = new_node!(tree, data)
        return s, s
    end

    # Alias for tree fields.
    left = tree.left
    right = tree.right

    # Find/insert recursively.
    c = tree.cmpfunc(data, tree.data[r])

    if c < 0
        # data < data[r]
        left[r], s = find_insert_rec!(tree, left[r], data)
    elseif c > 0
        # data > data[r]
        right[r], s = find_insert_rec!(tree, right[r], data)
    else
        # data == data[r]
        return r, r
    end

    # Fix the AVL property.
    if height(tree, left[r]) < height(tree, right[r]) - 1
        if height(tree, left[right[r]]) > height(tree, right[right[r]])
            right[r] = rotate_right!(tree, right[r])
        end

        return rotate_left!(tree, r), s

    elseif height(tree, left[r]) - 1 > height(tree, right[r])
        if height(tree, left[left[r]]) < height(tree, right[left[r]])
            left[r] = rotate_left!(tree, left[r])
        end

        return rotate_right!(tree, r), s
    end

    update_height!(tree, r)

    return r, s
end

The new_node! function is below.  I imagine Julia already implements such a strategy for push! in any case.
function new_node!(tree::AVLTree{T}, data::T) where {T}
    if length(tree.data) == tree.n
        resize!(tree.data, 2 * tree.n)
        resize!(tree.height, 2 * tree.n)
        resize!(tree.left, 2 * tree.n)
        resize!(tree.right, 2 * tree.n)
    end

    tree.n += 1
    tree.data[tree.n] = data
    tree.height[tree.n] = 0
    tree.left[tree.n] = 0
    tree.right[tree.n] = 0

    return tree.n
end


Possibly you'd get a perf improvement by replacing your usage of Vector with FixedSizeVector from FixedSizeArrays.jl: https://github.com/JuliaArrays/FixedSizeArrays.jl . Although note that the package requires Julia v1.11, currently released as beta only.

Apart from that, I don't think you can get a good answer without providing a minimal reproducing example.

The code is not so long but I think too long for a question.  BTW I am not using a dumb push! to add to the arrays; I am doubling their sizes when needed.  I can't imagine that's where the performance loss is.

When you do post your code, could you also post your implementation for push!? Julia's default implementation for Vector already uses an algorithm that has amortized constant time complexity.

This seems more of a topic for a Julia discourse thread than a question for SO...

Your resize! function may be taking too much time. You could try pre-allocating the arrays with a larger size that will not require adjusting (large enough to cover your use case) and retest the times without any resize!() usage. If you use BenchmarkTools.jl you can benchmark the various other functions during the run as well.
